# Laptop resolution cap below monitor 2560x1440

Tags: windows-7, resolution, hdmi, displayport

I have a few questions which Googling attempts have failed so asking here.

So I have a hp-7063sa laptop, I've hooked it up to a bigger screen ( dell u2515h)  to use it as a stationary machine.

The monitor is 2560x1440 I can't go that high from HDMI reasons due to bandwidth.( as it says when I try to create a custom resolution on  Intel's graphics program).

After reading around, I'm seeing lots of contradictory info about whether the HDMI bandwidth is supported or not at that res and 60Hz and I assume it was because of a different standard of HDMI. So question 1) how do I find out my standard of HDMI out from the laptop.

Then I looked around for reasons as to why I couldn't use the (dedicated GPU) Nvidia tools to create a custom res. There's a strange graphic on the settings for phsX on the Nvidia program,  it puts HDMI as something covered under the integrated GPU and the VGA covered under the D -GPU. Does that mean by VGA I could get to my monitors max res? (also VGA standards support this?) (since my screen doesn't have VGA, can I convert using a different cable type)

I can use mini display port on my MacBook air and that can go 2560x1440, simply by plug and play. After reading about this, a lot of people seem to be suggesting to use this port type/cable. Since my laptop hasn't got one of these, can I use a display port cable to support my efforts and then have a converter for the output port? (Extending from my previous thoughts about VGA)

If none of the above methods work can some suggest me a way or confirm you can't go that high from my laptop.

**Edit:**

Should probably I add I am using an HDMI High Speed with Ethernet cable (which I think is 1.4a but again still not sure)

found this for my dGPU - so VGA shouldn't go to the res I want, but it's got a maximum digital res, is this HDMI?

[GeForce GT 630M](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-630M/specifications)

**EDIT 2**

So I found out why dGPU settings don't support the changes of res and my hunch was true, it was because the VGA port is the only thing the dGPU handles in terms of output scaling.

[No 'display' tab in nVidia control panel..](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/496259/geforce-basics/no-39-display-39-tab-in-nvidia-control-panel-/)

**EDITS 3**

I could create a 2560x1440 40Hz custom resolution through the Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel (HDMI), unfortunately, when I switch to this, I get a dialog box saying my settings have now changed **but they haven't**. (I can tell as the input rate is shown on the monitor as 2048 x 1152 x 60Hz)

**EDIT 4**

I got the custom resolution to display, all I needed to do was restart my computer and the custom resolution then shows up on the windows screen resolutions picker.

Unfortunately, I'm not too sure what's wrong with it, but it's very wrong, moving the arrow makes the arrow all blurry and generally the screen looks bad. (could also be the dip from 60Hz to 40Hz, but I would have thought this wouldn't have been noticeable)

**EDIT 5**

according to this I should be able to output at 60Hz, since the HDMI standard can support a lot higher and my laptop outputs at the 1.4a.

[HP Pavilion dv6 Entertainment PC: Maintenance and Service Guide.](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03582006)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7947-force-dvi-hdmi-resolutions-refresh-rates-31.html

I had to change my timing setting on Intel Graphics panel from GTF to **CVT-RB**, this seems to give 55p max which is the closest I will get apparently